# Read the database to MapProperty Javafx

Tags: dictionary, javafx

I created MapProperty to read the information from the database as below.

The command runs fine with Map,ArrayList normal but error MapProperty.I want member to be ListProperty type so I can bind it to control

```
public MapProperty<String, ListProperty<String>> mapTaxonomy() {
        MapProperty<String, ListProperty<String>> mapTaxonomy = new SimpleMapProperty<>();
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String taxonomy = resultSet.getString("Taxonomy");
                ListProperty<String> memberSelector = mapTaxonomy.get(taxonomy);
                if (memberSelector == null) {
                    memberSelector = new SimpleListProperty<>();
                    mapTaxonomy.put(taxonomy, memberSelector);
                }
                memberSelector.add(resultSet.getString("Selector"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ParserService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return mapTaxonomy;
    }

@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        MapProperty<String, ListProperty<String>> mapTaxonomy = mapTaxonomy();
    }
```

After I run the following error statement,please help me

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)
    at javafx.beans.binding.MapExpression.put(MapExpression.java:262)
    at touya.akira.storages.database.table.parser.ParserService.mapTaxonomy(ParserService.java:70)
    at touya.akira.parser.styles.fixed.method.pagination.PaginationPresenter.initialize(PaginationPresenter.java:64)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 67 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of a `SimpleMapProperty` is a empty ***unmodifiable*** map. An exception is thrown when you try to modify it. Specify a modifiable `ObservableMap` as initial value to fix this issue.

```
MapProperty<String, ListProperty<String>> mapTaxonomy = new SimpleMapProperty<>(FXCollections.observableHashMap());
```

Comment: Thanks for @fabian your help I was successful, I have to find some oracle documentation about "default value of a SimpleMapProperty is a empty unmodifiable" I do not find tutorials on it.If possible
 please help me document,I refer more

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleMapProperty.html

Comment: @KiênĐịnh There doesn't seem to be any indication of it in the javadoc; I looked at the source code...